# Why is diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 used instead of diffie-hellman?

Tags: diffie-hellman, ssh

For SSH why is Diffie-Hellman-group1-sha1 used instead of just Diffie-Hellman? In other words, why is the hash function used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been specified by the standard, steps 4 and 5 of the protocol described in [RFC 4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-8):

> 2. S generates a random number y (0 < y < q) and computes
>    f = g^y mod p.  S receives e.  It computes K = e^y mod p,
>    H = **hash**(V_C || V_S || I_C || I_S || K_S || e || f || K)
>    (these elements are encoded according to their types; see below),
>    and signature s on H with its private host key.  S sends
>    (K_S || f || s) to C.  The signing operation may involve a
>    second hashing operation.

> 3. C verifies that K_S really is the host key for S (e.g., using
>    certificates or a local database).  C is also allowed to accept
>    the key without verification; however, doing so will render the
>    protocol insecure against *active attacks* (but may be desirable for
>    practical reasons in the short term in many environments).  C then
>    computes K = f^x mod p, H = **hash**(V_C || V_S || I_C || I_S || K_S
>    || e || f || K), and verifies the signature s on H.

> This value (H) is called the exchange hash, and it is used to
> **authenticate the key exchange**.  The exchange hash SHOULD be kept
> secret.

> The signature algorithm MUST be applied over H, not the original
> data.  Most signature algorithms include hashing and additional
> padding (e.g., "ssh-dss" specifies SHA-1 hashing).  In that case, the
> data is first hashed with HASH to compute H, and H is then hashed
> with SHA-1 as part of the signing operation.

It then goes to define diffie-hellman-group1-sha1, just to show that SHA-1 is indeed the hash mentioned above:

> The "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1" method specifies the Diffie-Hellman
> key exchange with SHA-1 as HASH, and Oakley Group 2 [RFC2409] (1024-
> bit MODP Group).  This method MUST be supported for interoperability
> as all of the known implementations currently support it.  Note that
> this method is named using the phrase "group1", even though it
> specifies the use of Oakley Group 2.

---

So basically it is a hash over the parameters used for the key exchange. Without it the parameters may be changed by an attacker (the "active attacks" in the description) and the exchange would not be authenticated.

Comment: When in doubt, read the standard.

Comment: Initially pointed to the wrong standard. That one basically described an identical scheme, so no harm to the answer otherwise. When in doubt, read the *correct* standard :)